# How to never show bar in full screen

Tags: menu-bar, fullscreen

This "new" functionality almost makes me regret buying a new Macbook. How on earth do I turn off the menu showing when the mouse hits the top? It's so incredibly annoying... I went full screen for a reason.

Comment: There used to be an option to choose where and which display the menu bar is on .. it shows as 'relocate menu bar' when you search in settings ... however, maybe it only shows with multiple displays ...

Comment: What's "new" about it?  macOS has been able to hide the menu bar (a broken behavior, if you ask me) since Sierra.  All Big Sur does is move the option, for no good reason.

Comment: It's actually been default behaviour since fullscreen was added, in Lion.